# Troubleshoot network application

Tags: windows, windows-xp, network-shares

I'm having an tough time troubleshooting an application that will not start properly after a move to a new domain controller. The first thing checked was permissions and exceptions in Windows Firewall but they appear correct. The vendor agrees that they are correct. The application works on some of the machines (the most imporant ones luckily) but not others. It also runs when logged in under Safe Mode. There is an AV, but even computers without the AV have this problem.

Knowing this, how can I troubleshoot (my assumption) what on this computer is blocking the application?

Comment: What is this application? What does it do? Any particular OS? Check things like firewalls (including Windows Firewall) and program access controls / make sure it has the permission to do what it can.

Comment: Application: Medisoft. It's a medical billing application on XP Pro. I've checked the firewall some of the computers work with the same firewall settings can connect the application. I'm looking to see if there are any other program access controls.